# Makefile analyzer/simulator?

Tags: makefile, analyzer

I'm no Makefile expert, and I was wondering if someone knew of some kind of analyzer or simulator that would start from the top-most Makefile all the way down to the inner-most Makefile, each time showing me the value of each variable and the order in which it goes through rules.

Thank you.

Comment: http://sailhome.cs.queensu.ca/~bram/makao/index.html may help you

Comment: It is worse than that - you can't even get make to tell you what is generated by your `$(eval $(call xx))`. Because I am not a copy-paste-modify programmer, I use `$(foreach)` and stuff and explicitly generate almost all recipes programmatically, with `.SUFFIX:` turning the craziness off. I don't want 9000 stat calls per source file make, thanks. Finding my source files isn't a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations of make offer the `-d` flag which will cause the program to print out everything it is doing, in great detail.  The `-n` flag will cause make to do a dry-run, ie report what it would do but not actually do it.

Be warned, make produces a lot of output so you probably want to redirect it to a file for your later perusal.

Comment: However, if an `include`-d file is out of date, `make -n` may still rebuild that with real commands. `make` wouldn't be able to infer *anything* valid if the `Makefile` or `include`d files were out of date.

Comment: Is this really what was asked for? in my experience, `make -d` will give you messages like "building target xxx", "trying rule yyy", which is good eg. for debugging parallel `make`, but won't give you a clue about code outside rules, and variable assignment/values.